# Gps location keeps bouncing to my neighbors house

Tags: gps, android-gps

So I have noticed this a few times. Suddenly while I am looking in maps or recently I have been doing geolocation stuff, and my location will randomly and precisely transfer from my home to my neighbors approximately a quarter mile away, specifically in the same location of his home each time it happens.

It is only for 2 or 3 seconds and then it bounces right backIt is only for 2 or 3 seconds and then it bounces right back to my current location at my home.

Any idea why this could be happening?

I turned my GPS on and off and the location accuracy but it continues to happen

Comment: Note: your question is not really about programming (but programmers may find it interesting). Probably the location is not given by GPS, but from other sources (e.g. WiFi). Your neighbor (maybe an other one) changed router or intensity, and so Google is thinking that with such intensity, you must be so much far from a router. Use an app which really use GPS, and go outside, and move around: let's Google to know where routers are. (but I think it want many unrelated people to do so or time, so it may take time/months).